# How can I effectively implement value categorizing(filtering)?

Tags: python

```
spearate_list = [160, 170, 180, 190]

def whichgroup(value, spearate_list)
    if value < spearate_list[0]:
        return 0
    elif spearate_list[0] <= value and value < spearate_list[1]:
        return 1
    elif spearate_list[1] <= value and value < spearate_list[2]:
        return 2
    elif spearate_list[2] <= value and value < spearate_list[3]:
        return 3
    else:
        return 4
```

`sepearte_list` could have various length range, say `spearate_list=[50,60,70,80,90,100]` and I want to implement this pythonic and efficient way.

Any advices please?

Comment: I think you are describing the standard `bisect` module. Your code looks like [this example](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html#other-examples) to me.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is not necessarily the most efficient one, but reasonably pythonic. First, augment your list to include both infinities;

```
separate_list = [-float('inf'), 160, 170, 180, 190, float('inf')]
```

Now, form a list of intervals and check if your value (say, `value=175`) is in any of the intervals (it must be in exactly one of them):

```
answer = [i for i,(x,y) in enumerate(zip(separate_list, separate_list[1:])) \
          if x <= value < y][0]
#2
```

Comment: OR ... `answer = bisect(spearate_list, value)`